# Quick Select C#

Tags: c#, sorting

I tried to implement 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect

> quickselect is a selection algorithm to find the *k*-th smallest element
>   in an unordered list.
>
> this is the Pseudo code I was following
>
> In quicksort, there is a subprocedure called partition that can, in
>   linear time, group a list (ranging from indices left to right) into
>   two parts: those less than a certain element, and those greater than
>   or equal to the element. Here is pseudocode that performs a partition
>   about the element `list[pivotIndex]`:
>
> ```
> function partition(list, left, right, pivotIndex)
>      pivotValue := list[pivotIndex]
>      swap list[pivotIndex] and list[right]  // Move pivot to end
>      storeIndex := left
>      for i from left to right-1
>          if list[i] < pivotValue
>              swap list[storeIndex] and list[i]
>              increment storeIndex
>      swap list[right] and list[storeIndex]  // Move pivot to its final place
>      return storeIndex
> ```
>
> This is known as the Lomuto partition scheme, which is simpler but
>   less efficient than Hoare's original partition scheme.
>
> In quicksort, we recursively sort both branches, leading to best-case
>   O(n log n) time. However, when doing selection, we already know which
>   partition our desired element lies in, since the pivot is in its final
>   sorted position, with all those preceding it in an unsorted order and
>   all those following it in an unsorted order. Therefore, a single
>   recursive call locates the desired element in the correct partition,
>   and we build upon this for quickselect:
>
> ```
>   // Returns the k-th smallest element of list within left..right inclusive
>   // (i.e. left <= k <= right).
>   // The search space within the array is changing for each round - but the list
>   // is still the same size. Thus, k does not need to be updated with each round.
>   function select(list, left, right, k)
>      if left = right        // If the list contains only one element,
>          return list[left]  // return that element
>      pivotIndex  := ...     // select a pivotIndex between left and right,
>                             // e.g., left + floor(rand() % (right - left + 1))
>      pivotIndex  := partition(list, left, right, pivotIndex)
>      // The pivot is in its final sorted position
>      if k = pivotIndex
>          return list[k]
>      else if k < pivotIndex
>          return select(list, left, pivotIndex - 1, k)
>      else
>          return select(list, pivotIndex + 1, right, k)
> ```

Please review the coding style and clarity

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace ArrayQuestions
{
    [TestClass]
    public class QuickSelect
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void QuickSelectAlgoTest()
        {
            int[] arr = {9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
            int[] res = Select(arr,  6);
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                Assert.IsTrue(res[i] <= 6, $"The res[i] {res[i]} was not greater than six");
            }
        }

        //Partially sort array such way that elements before index position n are smaller or equal than element at position n
        //And elements after n are larger or equal.
        public int[] Select(int[] input,int n)
        {
            //keep original array
            int[] partiallySortedArray = (int[])input.Clone();
            int startIndex = 0;
            var endIndex = input.Length - 1;
            var pivotIndex = n;
            Random r = new Random();
            while (endIndex > startIndex)
            {
                pivotIndex = QuickSelectPartition(partiallySortedArray, startIndex, endIndex, pivotIndex);
                if (pivotIndex == n)
                {
                    break;
                }
                if (pivotIndex > n)
                {
                    endIndex = pivotIndex - 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    startIndex = pivotIndex + 1;
                }

                pivotIndex = r.Next(startIndex, endIndex);
            }

            return partiallySortedArray;
        }

        private int QuickSelectPartition(int[] array, int startIndex, int endIndex, int pivotIndex)
        {
            int pivotValue = array[pivotIndex];
            Swap(ref array[pivotIndex], ref array[endIndex]);
            for (int i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++)
            {
                if (array[i].CompareTo(pivotValue) > 0)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                Swap(ref array[i], ref array[startIndex]);
                startIndex++;
            }
            Swap(ref array[endIndex], ref array[startIndex]);
            return startIndex;
        }

        private void Swap(ref int i, ref int i1)
        {
            int temp = i;
            i = i1;
            i1 = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @dfhwze this is like explaining what bubble sort is... I will edit, but Wiki link is the best description.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Separate code and test. It's great that you've written a unit test, but the test code should be in a separate class (and typically a separate project) from the code under test.

The testing could also be a bit more exhaustive. Given the same input you can test each value of `n`: it'll still run in milliseconds. A separate test could handle repeated elements. A third test could handle the extreme of repeated elements: if you have an array of length one million where every element is the same and you give `n = arr.Length / 2`, does the performance take a nose-dive? I suspect it does, and that's something you might want to address with a Dutch flag partition. Other corner cases would be `n = -1` or `n = arr.Length`: at present, I don't think either of those is particularly well handled.

---

`Select` as a name makes sense in context, but when you think about embedding it in a large project or library it isn't very specific. Naming things is hard: my best suggestion after two minutes' thought is `PartitionAroundMedian`.

---

`pivotIndex` is doing double duty. I think it would be clearer to separate out those duties; since I'm received a comment that this point was unclear, the first step in refactoring this would be

```
            var pivotIndexIn = n;
            Random r = new Random();
            while (endIndex > startIndex)
            {
                var pivotIndexOut = QuickSelectPartition(partiallySortedArray, startIndex, endIndex, pivotIndexIn);
                if (pivotIndexOut == n)
                {
                    break;
                }
                if (pivotIndexOut > n)
                {
                    endIndex = pivotIndexOut - 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    startIndex = pivotIndexOut + 1;
                }

                pivotIndexIn = r.Next(startIndex, endIndex);
            }
```

In fact, `QuickSelectPartition` doesn't strictly need to receive `pivotIndexIn` as an argument at all. If the reason for passing it in is to have a clear lifecycle of `r`, pass `r` instead.

Note that the scope of `pivotIndexOut` is narrowed to inside the loop body.

Since I'm talking about names: `r` is awful. My convention for instances of `Random` is to call them `rnd`; others might prefer `random` or `rng` (for *random number generator*).

---

I find it inconsistent to use the primitive type `int` for the array elements but `CompareTo` instead of the primitive `>` to compare them. Since it costs nothing, I would change the first: genericise the quick-select to operate on `T where T : IComparable<T>`.

---

The decision that `Select` does not modify its input can be reflected in the type signature by changing it from array to `IReadOnlyList<>` (or perhaps `IEnumerable<>` - see below). Similarly the return type could be `IList<>` or `IReadOnlyList<>` to indicate the expectation the method has of its user. (Personally I'd favour `IList<>`).

---

`Select`, `QuickSelectPartition`, and `Swap` don't use any instance members of the class, so you need a good reason *not* to make them all `static`. In fact, I'd be strongly tempted to make `Select` an extension method `public static IList<T> PartitionAroundMedian<T>(this IEnumerable<T> elements, int n) where T : IComparable<T>`.

---

> ```
>             for (int i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++)
>             {
>                 if (array[i].CompareTo(pivotValue) > 0)
>                 {
>                     continue;
>                 }
>                 Swap(ref array[i], ref array[startIndex]);
>                 startIndex++;
>             }
> ```

There are times when a quick-reject and `continue` makes for readable code. I don't think this is one of them.

```
            for (int i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++)
            {
                if (array[i].CompareTo(pivotValue) <= 0)
                {
                    Swap(ref array[i], ref array[startIndex]);
                    startIndex++;
                }
            }
```

is shorter and doesn't require mental effort to invert the condition.

---

> ```
>             while (endIndex > startIndex)
>             {
>                 pivotIndex = QuickSelectPartition(partiallySortedArray, startIndex, endIndex, pivotIndex);
>                 if (pivotIndex == n)
>                 {
>                     break;
>                 }
>                 ...
>             }
>
>             return partiallySortedArray;
> ```

I'd cut to the chase by putting the `return` where the `break` is.

---

Minor quibbles on whitespace: there's inconsistency over whether `,` in an argument list is followed by a space or not. And I'd prefer to put a blank line after every `}` unless the following line is another `}` or directly related to it (e.g. the `else` is directly related to the `if` block).

Comment: Could you be more specific about _pivotIndex is doing double duty_, I don't see that? `if (array[i].CompareTo(pivotValue) <= 0)`: Isn't it rather the original `>` that should be `>=`

Comment: @HenrikHansen, I've expanded on that first point. On the second, I was making an observation about readability rather than correctness. I haven't actually analysed for correctness: I just preserved the existing behaviour. Perhaps you could find a test case which the original code fails and add it to your answer?

Comment: OK, that is a very orthodox definition of double duty IMO :-). About the `>` vs `<=` - I were just referring to the wiki pseudo code.

Answer (score 4):

You are using an iterative approach which is normally faster than a recursive. That's a good optimization.

---

> ```
>             if (array[i].CompareTo(pivotValue) > 0)
>             {
>                 continue;
>             }
>             Swap(ref array[i], ref array[startIndex]);
>             startIndex++;
> ```

Why not just:

```
      if (array[i].CompareTo(pivotValue) < 0)
      {
        Swap(ref array[i], ref array[startIndex]);
        startIndex++;
      }
```

---

> ```
>       pivotIndex = r.Next(startIndex, endIndex);
> ```

The wiki is doing so but I don't see why instead of just taking the middle:

```
pivotIndex = startIndex + (endIndex - startIndex) / 2;
```

You could measure on a larger data set to see if there is any average difference in performance?

---

> `$"The res[i] {res[i]} was not greater than six"`

Strictly speaking: you are not finding values lesser than `6` but the six smallest values in the data set. (`n` or `k` is an index not a value)

Comment: I think you are right.